# regex - named group only if another named group matches

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

A toggle command can be used as follows:

```
toggle
toggle n
toggle >hotspot y
toggle >hotspot
toggle @location>hotspot n
toggle @location>hotspot
```

my regex at the moment is the following:

```
^toggle(?>\s(?>@(?'location'\w+))?(?>>(?'hotspot'\w+))?)?(?>\s(?'value'n|y))?$
```

this one however allows the following strings to match:

```
toggle @location
toggle @location n
```

I would like to allow the named group "location" (prefixed by "@") only if the named group "hotspot" (prefixed by ">") matches.

Comment: Hotspot should not be optional `^toggle(?>\s(?>@(?'location'\w+))?(?>>(?'hotspot'\w+)))?(?>\s(?'value'[ny]))?$` https://regex101.com/r/Vb1xHE/1

Comment: you're right, it was actually super simple! What about if hotspot was after value instead? I mean, is there a generic way to allow a group only if a prefix + a named group matches?

Comment: In that case you can use a positive lookahead assertion to make sure that the string contains at least what you require. You could then make the other groups optional I think.

Comment: I think this is a great example to investigate if you really need a regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the pattern that you tried, the group `hotspot` should not be optional.

There are also a few atomic groups `(?>` which are not necessary if you change the grouping a bit where the whitespace char can be matched optionally.

This part `n|y` can also be written as a character class `[ny]`

```
^toggle(?:\s(?:@(?'location'\w+))?>(?'hotspot'\w+))?(?:\s(?'value'[ny]))?$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `toggle` Match literally
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\s` Match a whitespace char
  - `(?:@(?'location'\w+))?` Optionally match `@`, capture in group `location` 1+ word chars
  - `>(?'hotspot'\w+)` Match `>`, capture in group `hotspot` 1+ word chars
- `)?` Close group and make it optional
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\s(?'value'[ny])` Match a whitespace char, capture in group `value` either `n` or `y`
- `)?` Close group and make it optional
- `$` End of string

[.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5etoggle%28%3f%3a%5cs%28%3f%3a%40%28%3f%27location%27%5cw%2b%29%29%3f%3e%28%3f%27hotspot%27%5cw%2b%29%29%3f%28%3f%3a%5cs%28%3f%27value%27%5bny%5d%29%29%3f%5cr%3f%24&i=toggle%0d%0atoggle+n%0d%0atoggle+%3ehotspot+y%0d%0atoggle+%3ehotspot%0d%0atoggle+%40location%3ehotspot+n%0d%0atoggle+%40location%3ehotspot%0d%0a%0d%0atoggle+%40location%0d%0atoggle+%40location+n&o=m)